# Error when Unzipping / Extracting Spring Tools Suite downloaded Zip / Jar file

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I downloaded the latest version of `spring tools suite`. It came in the form a `zip` / `jar` file which shows an error when i try to `unzip` it. It says there are insufficient files and it cannot unzip it and will be marked as corrupt.

I downloaded it 3 times and it shows the same `error`. Please help

Comment: Are you on Windows? If you cannot open the zip file in your explorer, I would guess that the ZIP file got corrupted during its download, for example by a proxy server or some other virus scanning system in the background. Could that be the case?

Answer (score 4):

`java -jar spring-tool-suite-4-4.11.1.RELEASE-e4.20.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar` works for me.

`sts-4.11.1.RELEASE` folder will be "extracted" and the `SpringToolSuite4.exe` is inside that folder.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently faced the following issue with the STS `4.9.0.RELEASE` version self-extracting jar. The self-extracting functionality is not working properly.

[image: Issue snapshot]

**Solution**
The simplest solution is extracting the `jar` using a zip file extractor tool such as (WinRAR/ 7ZIP), inside the extracted folder you could see another archive named `contents.zip`. Extract the `contents.zip` again using WinRAR/ 7ZIP, finally, you can find the STS IDE inside the extracted folder(**sts-4.9.0.RELEASE**) of `contents.zip` .

Answer (score 0):

@Rishit,

When you download the zip file, instead of saving it on the computer, if you can open it, that might solve the problem. It happened with me too.

Comment: "instead of saving it on the computer" you meant instead of extracting it after download?

Answer (score 0):

Even i had the same issue when i extract `spring tools 4`. Below are the steps i followed to fix the issue

**Step 1:**
Downloaded `Spring Tools 4` bundled `jar` from
[Spring Tools 4 Download](https://spring.io/tools)

**Step 2:** Right click downloaded `jar` and extract using `WinZip`

[image]

**Step 3:** Now unzip the contents.zip file using `WinZip` but it throws below error

[image]

**Step 4:** Here use `7Zip` to extract contents zip instead of `WinZip`:
Now it got extracted without any issue.

**Step 5:** Here we go, open `SpringToolSuite4.ini` and add below

```
openFile
-vm
C:/jdk/jdk1.8/bin/javaw
```

**Step 6:** Thats it, open SpringToolSuite4.exe

Please note, you may use 7Zip for the steps wherever i mentioned WinZip.

Click Up Vote if this is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just unzip the .zip file and there you will find a contents.zip .
2. Extract the contents.zip there you can find the you can find the springtoolsuit
3. get all the files and paste it in your desired directory and create a shortcut
4. click on the shortcut and you are good to go